# mysqli query response remain empty despite connection to database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, google-cloud-datastore

I use mysqli to connect with remote mysql db. I don't get any connection errors however when I type a testing query my $response variable in console displays only five lines of blank space. Here is my connection code:

```
        ini_set ('error_reporting', E_ALL);
        ini_set ('display_errors', '1');
        error_reporting (E_ALL|E_STRICT);

        $connection = mysqli_init();
        mysqli_options ($connection, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT, true);

        mysqli_ssl_set($connection,'/usr/local/certs/client-key.pem',
       '/usr/local/certs/client-cert.pem', '/usr/local/certs/server-ca.pem', NULL, NULL);

        $link = mysqli_real_connect ($connection, $db['host'], 
       $db['user'],$db['password'], $db['dbName'], 3306, NULL,MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL_DONT_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT);


        if (!$link)
        {   
            die ('Connect error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . '): ' . mysqli_connect_error() . "\n");
        } 
        else 
        {   
            $this->output->writeln($link); // this returns '1'
            $response = $connection->query('SHOW TABLES;');
            $this->output->writeln($response); // here I get blank lines 
            // even if tables exist within database


            $connection->close();
        }
```

**Notice:** since that mysql remote server uses google cloud I had some troubles with connection because of SSL certificates. So I found I need to put MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL_DONT_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT flag in order avoid problems. That might be important issue.

Comment: After you run `$response = $connection->query('SHOW TABLES;');` You still have to run some sort of `fetch` to actually return the results of the query

Comment: How can I fetch that query in display it in console? I'm a little newbie in PHP but I thought that is a proper way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all cases executing the query, does not return you the results of that query.
The query if it is successful just returns you a handle to use to go and fetch the results of that query.

So you need to add some sort of mysqli_fetch to go and get each row of the resultset one at a time. See amended code

In this case because the result of a SHOW TABLES is a little unusual, I used a `fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)` to make processing the results easier, but normally you would be more likely to use `fetch_assoc()` or `fetch_object()`

```
<?php
ini_set ('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set ('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting (E_ALL|E_STRICT);

$connection = mysqli_init();
mysqli_options ($connection, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT, true);

mysqli_ssl_set($connection,
                '/usr/local/certs/client-key.pem',
                '/usr/local/certs/client-cert.pem', 
                '/usr/local/certs/server-ca.pem', 
                NULL, NULL);

$link = mysqli_real_connect ($connection, $db['host'],
                             $db['user'],$db['password'], 
                             $db['dbName'], 3306, NULL,
                             MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL_DONT_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT);

if (!$link) {
    $this->output->writeln('Connect error (' . 
                        mysqli_connect_errno() . '): ' . 
                        mysqli_connect_error() . "\n"
                    );
} else {   
    $this->output->writeln($link); // this returns '1'
    $response = $connection->query('SHOW TABLES;');

    while ( $row = $response->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        $this->output->writeln($row[0]);
    }

    $connection->close();
}
```